# Why does this give a Typescript warning?

Tags: typescript, create-react-app, react-router-dom

Why does the second call to `needsString(var1)` in this .tsx component give a warning, but not the first or third calls? And if I change the code to use `var2` instead of `var1` (which I think have exactly the same types), I don't get a warning. What gives?

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const DeleteTeams2 = ({ var2 } : { var2: string | undefined})=> {
    // use var here so that var1 and var2 get exactly the same types
    var { var1 } = useParams();

    function needsString(str : string) : string {
        return "hello";
    }

    // I can tell typescript that var1
    // definitely is non-null with an if statement
    if (! var1)
        throw new Error("bad, bad varN");

    // This call is warning-free
    needsString(var1);

    // But JSX doesn't know that var1 is non-null for some reason...
    return (
        <div
            onClick={() => {
                // I get a warning from this!
                needsString(var1);
            }}
        >
            { needsString(var1) }
        </div>
    )
}
```

When I move the mouse over the definitions of both `var1` and `var2`, they both seem to have the same type: `var varN: string | undefined`.

Due to the if statement, I expect `var1` to behave as a `string` after the if statement. And indeed it does for `var2`, but not for `var1`.

But I get a warning from the first call to `needsString(var1)`:

```
TypeScript error in /path/to/foobar.tsx(146,29):
Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.  TS2345

    144 |             onClick={() => {
    145 |                 // I get a warning from this!
  > 146 |                 needsString(var1);
        |                             ^
    147 |             }}
    148 |         >
    149 |             { needsString(var1) }
```

Edit: Removed reference to [Non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator) as I was not using a Non-null assertion operator as several comments have pointed out.

Comment: Probably works if you have `const { var1 }`

Comment: *"Due to the if statement and Non-null assertion operator,..."* Your `!` in the `if` is not the non-null assertion operator, it's just the negation operator. The non-null assertion operator is a postfix operator and isn't used for logical flow. But that `if` should be acting as a guard, this is just a terminology comment. :-)

Comment: @VLAZ - It should work with `let` as well, provided `var1` isn't modified between the guard and the use.

Comment: Thank you for comments that I wasn't in fact using a non-null assertion operator. I've edited the question to not say that.

Comment: What compiler and builder do you use can you include more info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the code here:

```
onClick={() => {
  // I get a warning from this!
  needsString(var1);
}}
```

will not be executed at the same time as this code:

```
if (! var1)
  throw new Error("bad, bad varN");

// This call is warning-free
needsString(var1);
```

Moreover, `var1` is a mutable reference, so from TypeScript's perspective it *might* change between checking if it's empty you actually using it. For example consider this sample code:

```js
//it's populated
var myVar = "hello";

//verify it's populated
if(!myVar) throw Error("WRONG!");

//absolutely positively `myVar` is populated

//set this to execute later
setTimeout(() => console.log("myVar", myVar));

//change it
myVar = undefined;
```

So, TypeScript can only determine that `var1` *might* be reassigned. The `useParams()` function returns an object typed as

```
{ [K in keyof Params]?: string | undefined; }
```

which means that the possible type for `var1` is just `string | undefined`. *If* the value changes (TypeScript has no way to determine if it does or not), then it can see that `undefined` is not allowed.

## Use `const`

You can simple declare it as `const { var1 }` ([Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4AoUSWOAbzgFcBnJABRShRCbgF85suAkXQwAtDgYwkUMQBNcZcuTQQAdk3gARJABsk0gCqpuAJjgBeOAAp6ANw7n+ALjpwHUU681RgagOZwAD6ManJImH5IcrwAlBYAfHTkcKlwAPTpjCzuHHAAFjJIcEwQcDD5KPAeAIxwKGG5nnD+BnBIAB6iugCe5YUlXMUwPWBITClpqhrw9hx1-FbMbBxcTNaxFJOpmAxqGMDqcGpI0UwAyjC+AdY+cN5Xfv6x9yWPAclpX3BEMAxQagIhV0uggSi+vGUX0ycAAknA0A1ynpdOVRuM0L4wPAKlUmjVthksuFImpgNJenBgDw1OoxGoGCC4AB3cn5eqA4CYN5VJAgJBqGCErk2ACE+NihK+FRwzOOSDlAFEoDgoNZ8AAjFByAA0cC1ciaADl8JsoWkYYZ8tSESgmTbmRwyQExNhToSTmdLtd-NZambCTCAEJSOAAKXOAA04ApxmoAOTwADWtLluOq8ypNLpDKZmGgJVwxREpTUADoK4Tfv9AdYpWkADxyYB2evfODqADCumAaCTFloG0sSVobfbFqy8Na8BQLKdTwEODwFWporH4-lXvevv9FA3EMhG4S67S9E9cgu2798xeh-HDfSzbsx6+kt4QA)) which makes its type `string` only as it assures the compiler you'd not change it between declaration and usage.

## Type assertion

Alternatively, explicitly set the type to only `string`: `var { var1 } = useParams() as { var1: string };` [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4AoUSWOAbzgFcBnJABRShRCbgF85suAkXQwAtDgYwkUMQBNcZcuTQQAdk3gARJABsk0gCqpuAJjgBeOAAp6ANw7n+ALjpwHUU681RgagOZwAD6ManJImH5IcrwAlBYAfHTkcKlwAPTpjCzuHHAAFjJIcEwQcDD5KPAeAIxwKGG5nnD+BnBIAB6iugCe5YUlXMUwPWBITClpHm61fJbZbBxcTNax9Tz2HDXeML4BfBSTqZgMahjA6nBqSNFMAMq7fv7WPnA7e-5r70-JaX9wRBgDCgagIhV0uggSj+vGUf0ycAAknA0A1ynpdOVRuM0L4wPAKlUmjUjhksuFImpgNJenBgDw1OoxGoGBC4AB3an5eqg4CYEowKpIEBINQwUl8mwAQmJsVJfwqOHZVyQyoAolAcFBrPgAEYoOQAGjg+rkTQAcvhYod4VlDPl6SiUGzHeyOFSAmJsDdSddbg8PtZata4WkEQAhKRwABSdwAGnAFOM1AByeAAa0ZysJ1S2dIZTJZbMw0BKuGKIlKagAdLXSYDgaDrPK0gAeOTAOwt-5wdQAYV0wDQ6YstFWliStG7PbDWWRrXgKA57p+gjwFXpUunM5V-seASDWxDO5hsJ3CW3aXofrk933z2DfGnrfSHbsF7+ct4QA). The compiler would accept that *maybe* you've reassigned it but it would at least know that the only possible thing you would change the variable to is another string. Which satisfies the type used later and would thus work. However, that requires a type assertion and as always, it relies on you being *sure* this would be the case, otherwise you might get a runtime error that the TypeScript compiler cannot see (because you've "blinded" it, intentionally)

## `const` only after a check

If you feel uneasy setting `var1` to a constant for whatever reason - either you change it or anything else, then you can just do your normal check for `var1` and then set a new constant:

```
if (! var1)
  throw new Error("bad, bad varN");

const checkedVar1 = var1;

/* ... */

onClick={() => {
  // I get a warning from this!
  needsString(checkedVar1);
}}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4AoUSWOAbzgFcBnJABRShRCbgF85suAkXQwAtDgYwkUMQBNcZcuTQQAdk3gARJABsk0gCqpuAJjgBeOAAp6ANw7n+ALjpwHUU681RgagOZwAD6ManJImH5IcrwAlBYAfHTkcKlwAPTpjCzuHHAAFjJIcEwQcDD5KPAeAIxwKGG5nnD+BnBIAB6iugCe5YUlXMUwPWBITClpHm61fJbZbBxcTNaxFJOpmAxqGMDqcGpI0UwAyjC+AdY+cN7nfv6xNyV3Aclp73BEMAxQagSFul0ECU714ynemTgAEk4GgGuU9LpyqNxmhfGB4BUqk0ahsMllwpE1MBpL04MAeGp1GI1AxAXAAO4k-L1P7ATDPKpIEBINQwPHsmwAQhxsTx7wqOAZByQ0oAolAcFBrPgAEYoOQAGjg6rkTQAcvg1uC0qoNPA0IU0ABraIANQ4dSstXWEKyhnyFNhKHpXoZHGJATE2COeMOxzOF381lqxrxkIAQlI4AApE4ADTgCnGagA5PBrVTpVjqo7yZTqbT6ZhoCVcMURKU1AA6Vt4r4-P7WcVpAA8cmAdh7Hzg6gAwrpgDaLLRVpYkrRhyO0pCYa14ChGQH7gIcHgKhShUvlzKIy9o5akDb7Y7jSfQWCTwlj2l6OG5KdzzHb3wl730gOdjPu8Yq8EAA)

This still works and will satisfy the TypeScript compiler that `checkedVar1` (I assume you'd name it something more sensible) is not changed between definitely being being assigned something that's definitely a string and when it's actually used.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder [OK, tricked it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMAKBDK2SpwC+cAZlBCHAERTrYDGMAtBcjOlMwCaXUDcAKEEMIAO1TwAIugA26DgBV6BAExwAvHAAUASg0A+RILim4AN1yILuAIzFNKDDjwE9Qk2dLIxTYOLgxdHRuVABlGChgMQBzbUkoOAAuOATomN1k1Mj04zN8uDoYZCgxGgALOVkIAU9TImF84FIdAEIbKFtdOoKYcooAd0D0IYBRKAoobWoAI2xuABo4Oe4OgDlqXQ98oJDwnNjtS06txrMikrLtHvyAHm5gcxuC03EAYVlgBgBrDQQ9TRGBDPF75AD0YLgAEk4DEFHBsHABrgxLlyJQ4H1gKhWiDQaZdqEIlFDscukJ8fkiA18QY8fkkIT9iS4mTMjTQbcwQ9zHT8t0iEA) I removed some comments and dead code. Seems to error in the callback as OP says.

Comment: In TS Config, make sure you have JSX set to React (I think that's the default). Then I got it to stop complaining by doing `import React from "react";`, which kind of surprised me. :-) I had thought I'd have to go off and get a cdnjs or unpkg link for it, but that worked on its own.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder [here it is with React](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMAKBDK2SpwC+cAZlBCHAERTrYDGMAtBcjOlMwCaXUDcAKFCRYcAEr0mZClVpSYAwYIYQAdqngARdABt0HACr0CAJjgBeOAAoAlBYB8iQXFdwAbrkQfcARmKWKBg4eAR2Qi5upMhqTMDqcGro6NyoAMowUMBqAObWmlBwAFxwBdk5tsWlmeXObvVwdDDIUGo0ABZ6uhBK9UTK9cCkNgCEPlC+tpENcDDtFADuiehLAKJQFFDW1ABG2NwANHB73OMActS2EfVJKek1udaeE1cDbk0tbdbTDQA83MB3D8Zq51ABhXTABgAawsCDslicCGBIPqAHo0XAAJJwHIGODYOALXBqWrkSizdrAVAjFGo1y3VIZLKPZ6TIT0txEfqohx0hpIRn3Fl5NmVHkg35ogHuPn1KZEIA) I used "preserve" for the last one.

Comment: Odd that it happens in your example but not mine (see comment on the question). But yours seems closer to what the OP's doing, so... Yet another reason to use `const` for state variables in FCs. I'm not convinced by the explanation, but `const` does seem to fix it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ah, I finally got around to seeing your link. Your `useParams` returns `{[key: string]: string}` while the one that's imported returns `{[key: string]?: string | undefined}`, so that's the difference. I guess it makes sense - you might check for a property and it might be there or not, depending on all sorts of things. React and TS can't guarantee a property would exist and it even if it does, it wouldn't be empty.

Comment: That makes sense, I meant to have `| undefined` there. :-) Fundamentally, though, what this comes down to is that the TypeScript compiler doesn't always accurately detect that nothing assigns to (and nothing *can* assign to) a variable. That's at least partially because the TypeScript team are often making pragmatic decisions about complexity and capability vs. compilation speed.