# Why types inside the .forEach callback function not respecting the undefined check in typescript?

Tags: typescript

Please the take this example:

```js
// typescript
function test(foo: {details?: Record<string, unknown>}) {
  // undefined check
  if (!foo.details) {
    return;
  }
  
  console.log(foo.details['uff']); // ==> no issue here
  
  let i;
  for (i of ['a', 'b']) {
    console.log(foo.details[i]); // No issues here
  }
  
  ['a', 'b'].forEach(el => {
    console.log(foo.details[el]);
    //          ^^^^^^^^^^^==============> Error: Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)
  })
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFApgZygCmHOAuRAbwBMUoBDGAGzQH4CAlFCOAJ2IB4NWYwBzADSJwAazBwA7mAB8AXwCURALAAoRIhjBEmAIQ44AOlIVqaRYVXr1rMiFZgA3JcSzVzqmQ1O1iHK20wiHBaANoA5ORhQmEARmEAuubO6ixgaHAeBlRwfNi4RmSUNCEwiQ6IAPQViAC8NdKIAHJwGmhoIOiIABYoNs6uKs7hkdFx8QZ+AKLkEF2YKFS1DRY+KQjpmdm5+gUmxQtlyZXVVqfqAHqXV9fndXf3Dw2TrKxsBADyMQBWzFCtiAAHOBtGAxKgAT0QYXApGAvBQxDCBigaEwACYAKwAZjR8n6eJUsiAA)

Why do I'm getting this `Object is possibly 'undefined'` error even though I'm checking for it just above it?

Comment: @Terry if that was true, then `foo.details[i]` would also show an error. The real problem is the callback - it's a technical detail but TS cannot guarantee that when that function runs the property will be there. Although, logically it should be. It's just because it's a separate function call that *might* come "later" according to the compiler.

Comment: if you are sure that this isnt `null` or `undefined` then you can put an exclamation mark after the details `console.log(foo.details![el]);`

Comment: @Ifaruki I know that. But that sounds like defeating the purpose of the compiler type checking.

Comment: It's possible that the TypeScript flow-based logic is being conservative and considering that the callback might possibly be asynchronous, in which case the caller of `test()` could modify the `details` property, rendering the "undefined check" stale by the time the callback is invoked.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts that's what happens. For TS, what you have there is a function which means it would be executed *later*. As such, it's not possible to guarantee that the state of `foo` is going to be the same between execution and definition time. Now *we* as programmers can make that inference because we know that the function is going to be executed before anything else has modifies `foo`. However, that's not applicable in all cases and it's more work for the compiler to try and find this out. [Similar problem here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60815482).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you're passing as an argument to `forEach` is just that : An argument. As TypeScript, there's no way to know when that function is going to be executed. In our case we're sure that `forEach` will execute it immediately, but TypeScript can't know that for sure.

However, in your case the problem resides in the fact that the `foo` object is mutable, and that TS thinks `details` may be unreferenced. If you just extract `details` to pass it directly to the callback function, the problem disappears and the resulting code works :

```
function test(foo: {details?: Record<string, unknown>}) {
  if (!foo.details) {
    return;
  }

  let i;
  for (i of ['a', 'b']) {
    console.log(foo.details[i]); // ==> No issues here
  }

  const { details } = foo;

  ['a', 'b'].forEach(el => {
    console.log(details[el]); // Works alright !
  })
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFApgZygCmHOAuRAbwBMUoBDGAGzQH4CAlFCOAJ2IB4NWYwBzADSJwAazBwA7mAB8AXwCURALAAoRIhjBEmAIQ44AOlIVqaRYVXr1rMiFZgA3JcSzVzqmQ1O1iHK20wiHBaANoA5ORhQmEARmEAuubO6ixgaHAeBlRwfNi4RmSUNCEwiQ6IAPQViAC8NdKIAHJwGmhoIOiIABYoNs6uKs6pGESIxkVoLrW+uN7O4ZHRcfEGfgCi5BBdmChUtQ0WPikI6ZnZueOmIbtlldUA6mwik+RUPHxdUP3yqrJAA)