# A type error of "MediaStream" occurs when using "addTrack" in React's useRef

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typeerror, use-ref, mediastream

A type error occurs in `myStreamRef.current` inside `addTrack`.

```
const myStreamRef = useRef<MediaStream>();
...
if (myStreamRef.current) {
  myStreamRef.current.getTracks().forEach((track) => {
    peerRef.current?.addTrack(track, myStreamRef.current);
  });
}
```

```
Argument of type 'MediaStream | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MediaStream'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'MediaStream'.
```

As shown below, if you eliminate the possibility of being `undefined` once more with the `if` statement, the error will no longer occur.
But I've already removed the possibility of being `undefined` with the outermost `if` statement, so I don't know why I have to regroup it.
If you know the answer or know of a cleaner way to solve this, please let me know.

```
const myStreamRef = useRef<MediaStream>();
...
if (myStreamRef.current) {
  myStreamRef.current.getTracks().forEach((track) => {
    if (myStreamRef.current) {  
      peerRef.current?.addTrack(track, myStreamRef.current);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why types inside the .forEach callback function not respecting the undefined check in typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65000003/why-types-inside-the-foreach-callback-function-not-respecting-the-undefined-che)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem arose because the internal methods had to operate independently.